# how to add spaces before every line of text in a text file using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

hi i have this lines in my text file:

```
Registrant State/Province: 
Registrant Postal Code: 
Reistrant Country: 
Registrant Phone: 
Admin Name: 
Admin Organization: 
Admin Street: 
Admin City:
```

how to add spaces like 5 to 10 spaces before every line using excel vba.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this in Excel VBA?

Comment: because everytime i import all this data into my excel say registrant country, rightafter the country say USA the next line will be include that it will look like USARegistrant. if only i can have spaces before each line maybe it will be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy of the file with spaces, after rename...

```
Dim s, s1 As String
Dim xx As String

s = "e:\0\a\Space.txt"
s1 = "e:\0\a\Space.dat"
Open s For Input As #1
Open s1 For Output As #2
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, xx
    Print #2, Space(10) & xx
Wend
Close #1
Close #2

Kill s
Name s1 As s
```

Changing a little the code, You can add spaces or other data where you want inside the line.